# MongoDB greaterThan many values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an API built with Node + Mongoose, and now I want to filter the data using some fields. Everything works fine, but how can I get the data like: `1 < age < 3 AND 8 < age < 11`

I am trying this:

```
query.where('age').gte(1).lte(3);
query.where('age').gte(8).lte(11);
```

but this code only gets me `8 < age < 11`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), since an [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) condition cannot possibly overlap where you condition would be true:

```
{
    "$or": [
        { "age": { "$gte": 1, "$lte": 3 } },
        { "age": { "$gte": 8, "$lte": 11 } }
    ]
}
```

Also you are using JavaScript which has a nice free flowing object notation, so the helper methods are really overkill here. Use the [standard query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/) syntax instead.

Just a demo to show different forms of representing the same query:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var testSchema = new Schema({
  "age": Number
});

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema, 'testcol' );

var query = Test.where({
  "$or": [
    { "age": { "$gte": 1, "$lte": 3 } },
    { "age": { "$gte": 8, "$lte": 11 } }
  ]
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( query._conditions, undefined, 2 ) );


var query2 = Test.where().or([
  { "age": { "$gte": 1, "$lte": 3 } },
  { "age": { "$gte": 8, "$lte": 11 } }
]);

console.log( JSON.stringify( query2._conditions, undefined, 2 ) );

var query3 = Test.where().or(
  [
    Test.where("age").gte(1).lte(3)._conditions,
    Test.where("age").gte(8).lte(11)._conditions
  ]
);

console.log( JSON.stringify( query3._conditions, undefined, 2 ) );
```

Which should also demonstrate that the "helpers" are not really adding much value to how the query is basically formed.

Comment: How can I do this with Mongoose, I already have an query variable with some other conditions, I am trying something like this:
`query.or(where('age').gte(1).lte(3));
query.or(where('age').gte(8).lte(11));`

Comment: Umm. `Model.find({ "$or": [ ...etc })` Mongoose does not "restrict" you to using those helpers. I mentioned that because you don't seem to realize this. Just use the standard notation. It's easier to understand.